# can cocoa framework use struct as interface function parameter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, struct

i wrote a framework for my test app,the framework supports three functions for test app call,my question is one interface function uses struct as passed in parameter,when i call this function from test app(of couese i public the include file which defines the strcut),test app can not compile successfully,so framework interface function can not use struct as parameter?

next code is call sample code:

```
ImageInfoStructRef errorInfo;
[[SMModuleUtility defaultModuleUtility] getImageInfo:errorInfo];
```

there is framework interface include file:

```
- (void)getImageInfo:(ImageInfoStructRef)errorInfo;
```

Comment: You need to provide more details for people to be able to help you without guessing. What is `ImageInfoStructRef`? What is the compile error? What does `getImageInfo:` do with its parameter? Etc.

Comment: ImageInfoStructRef is a struct point,my question is very simple, i want to know wheter or not framework interface function can use C struct as passed in parameter?

Comment: Yes, a struct can be used as a parameter. However you are not using a struct as a parameter but rather a *pointer* to a struct, which is rather different; doing that is also valid *provided* it is done correctly. You are getting an, as yet, unspecified error, so you've done something wrong. What you've written so far is not sufficient to determine what that is. If you provide at least the answers to the questions somebody maybe able to help you.